Deleting Django migrations in the auth app
I have a migration that was created for the built in django auth app and we realized it was a bad idea and want to completely remove it because its buggy. however since this migration was for the pre built auth app i have no clue where to find it in the directory to even remove it? We have a staging and production environment we'd need to apply this change to as well and Im unsure how to remove and where to even remove this change from

How did you even apply this change to a staging and production environment if you don't know where to make this change? I've closed this as a duplicate that will show you how to find the modules code. That alone wouldn't have worked for deployments, are you sure you've actually deployed this? I am guessing you've not really changed the apps models / deployed it. If you really have, please [edit] to add proper details in the question and reply to my comment, I'll reopen the question.
